# How to remove value of each key in Async Storage in React Native at the time of Logout

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I am using `async` storage in React native to store response getting from server. Now i want to remove value of each key at the time of logout.but method of `removeItem` is not able to do that here is my code...

```
logout = ()=>{

   const {id , storedValue ,storedType,profileImg,type } = this.state;
   console.log("here" , id);
    axios.post('api/v1/user/do_logout', {
      user_id: id,

        })
        .then( async (response) => {
          if(response.data.type == "success"){
             alert("Logout Successfully");
             await AsyncStorage.removeItem(storedValue);
             await AsyncStorage.removeItem(storedType);
             await AsyncStorage.removeItem(profileImg);
             await AsyncStorage.removeItem(type);
             await AsyncStorage.removeItem(id);

            console.log(storedValue , storedType , profileImg , type ,id );
            this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen");

          }else if(response.data.type == "error"){
            // console.log(self.id);
            alert("Incorrect Detail");
          }
      })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

In the above code i am trying to remove value of each key but it is not working. kindly help

Comment: Try `AsyncStorage.clear()`. This will remove complete AsyncStorage.

Comment: If you insist to remove one by one then this may help you `AsyncStorage.removeItem(storedValue.toString());`

Comment: @Vencovsky what is the point in marking duplicate and giving answer for same question?

Comment: Try `logout = async () => {}`

Comment: @ravibagul91 now I just realized it's not a dupe. Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 4):

> i am trying to remove value of each key but it is not working.

You might think that because you call `console.log(storedValue , storedType , profileImg , type ,id );` it's not clearing, but probably, it's clearing, you are showing the state of the component, not the value in `AsyncStorage`.

If this isn't the case, please explain better on what you mean by `but it is not working`.

One way to remove all at once is using `AsyncStorage.multiRemove`.

```
await AsyncStorage.multiRemove([storedValue, storedType, profileImg, type, id])
```

> You should notice that `storedValue`, `storedType`, `profileImg`, `type`, `id` needs to be the `key` that you used in `AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)` and not the `value`.

You can also remove all stored keys from your app with `getAllKeys` and `multiRemove`.

```
AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
    .then(keys => AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys))
    .then(() => alert('All Keys removed'));
```